# How to read multiple .mat files (which are too large to fit in memory) using tensorflow dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, pickle, tensorflow-datasets

I have around 550K samples, each sample being 200x50x1. The size of this dataset is around 57GB.

I want to train a network on this set but I am having trouble reading it.

```
batch_size=8

def _read_py_function(filename,labels_slice):
    with h5py.File(filename, 'r') as f:
        data_slice = np.asarray(f['feats'])
        print(data_slice.shape)
    return data_slice, labels_slice

placeholder_files = tf.placeholder(tf.string, [None])
placeholder_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((placeholder_files,placeholder_labels))
dataset = dataset.map(
    lambda filename, label: tuple(tf.py_func(
        _read_py_function, [filename,label], [tf.uint8, tf.int32])))

dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=50000)
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)

iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(dataset.output_types, dataset.output_shapes)
data_X, data_y = iterator.get_next()
data_y = tf.cast(data_y, tf.int32)

net = conv_layer(inputs=data_X,num_outputs=8, kernel_size=3, stride=2, scope='rcl_0')
net = pool_layer(inputs=net,kernel_size=2,scope='pl_0')

net = dropout_layer(inputs=net,scope='dl_0')

net = flatten_layer(inputs=net,scope='flatten_0')
net = dense_layer(inputs=net,num_outputs=256,scope='dense_0')
net = dense_layer(inputs=net,num_outputs=64,scope='dense_1')
out = dense_layer(inputs=net,num_outputs=10,scope='dense_2')
```

And I run the session using :

```
sess.run(train_iterator, feed_dict = {placeholder_files: filenames, placeholder_labels: ytrain})
        try:
            while True:
                _, loss, acc = sess.run([train_op, loss_op, accuracy_op])
                train_loss += loss 
                train_accuracy += acc
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            pass
```

But I am getting the error even before running the session :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SFCC-trial-134.py", line 297, in <module>
    net = rcnn_layer(inputs=data_X,num_outputs=8, kernel_size=3, stride=2, scope='rcl_0')
  File "SFCC-trial-134.py", line 123, in rcnn_layer
    reuse=False)
  File "SFCC-trial-134.py", line 109, in conv_layer
    reuse         = reuse
  File "/home/priyam.jain/tensorflow-gpu-python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/arg_scope.py", line 183, in func_with_args
    return func(*args, **current_args)
  File "/home/priyam.jain/tensorflow-gpu-python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py", line 1154, in convolution2d
    conv_dims=2)
  File "/home/priyam.jain/tensorflow-gpu-python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/arg_scope.py", line 183, in func_with_args
    return func(*args, **current_args)
  File "/home/priyam.jain/tensorflow-gpu-python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py", line 1025, in convolution
    (conv_dims + 2, input_rank))
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not NoneType
```

I though about using TFRecords but had a hard time creating those. Couldn't find a good post where I learn to create them for my kind of dataset.

conv_layer is defined as follows :

```
def conv_layer(inputs, num_outputs, kernel_size, stride, normalizer_fn=None, activation_fn=nn.relu, trainable=True, scope='noname', reuse=False):

    net = slim.conv2d(inputs = inputs,
        num_outputs   = num_outputs,
        kernel_size   = kernel_size,
        stride        = stride,
        normalizer_fn = normalizer_fn,
        activation_fn = activation_fn,
        trainable     = trainable,
        scope         = scope,
        reuse         = reuse
        )
    return net
```

Comment: Can you share the code being used in your `rcnn_layer` and `conv_layer`. Also which version of TensorFlow are you using?

Comment: My tensorflow version is 1.10.0 and I have updated the question.

Comment: One meantime hack can be to load the dataset in chunks, train, load next chunk , train and so on

Comment: actually each file contains only one class, so I don't think that would be a good idea @fireball.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not pass `tf.py_func` inside your map function. You can read the file image by passing the function name directly inside your `map` function. I am posing only the relevant parts of the code.

```
def _read_py_function(filename, label):
    return tf.zeros((224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32), tf.ones((1,), dtype=tf.int32)

dataset = dataset.map(lambda filename, label: _read_py_function(filename, label))
```

Another change is your `iterator` will expect only floating point of input. So you will have to change your `tf.uint8` type of output to `float`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, actually I was about to post that I am now able to create tfrecords and am using those, but still appreciate the gesture. Thanks and will remember this answer for future.